# Maven dependencies not visible in WEB-INF/lib

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, maven, web-inf

I'm having this weird problem making my project Maven-based. I created a new **Maven** project in Eclipse and enabled the Dynamic Web facets. But during runtime now it throws `ClassNotFoundException` because the Maven dependencies are not copied to `WEB-INF/lib` directory. I even tried adding the *copy-dependencies* section in POM, but it didn't help.

Someone [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/488042/tools/maven-web-inf) seemed to have solved this the right way, but I guess he forgot to mention the solution ::(

Comment: Try the latest m2eclipse plugin. I think there are two parts to it and it helped me with getting the maven dependencies on the eclipse class path.

Comment: To make maven play nice with wtp, I had to install the core and the extras from here: http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/installing-m2eclipse.html

Comment: @xecaps thanks, but i had already done this

Answer (score 176, accepted):

This should have nothing to do with eclipse and m2eclipse, and optionally for better support - [m2e-wtp](http://community.jboss.org/en/tools/blog/2011/09/30/m2eclipse-wtp-0140-new-noteworthy). Also, you don't need copy-dependencies. Here are a few possible reasons:

- you should invoke `mvn package` (or right-click > maven > package) and obtain a war file - the `<packaging>` (in the pom) must be `war`
- your dependencies should be with the default scope (if they are `provided` or `test` they will not be included in the archive)
- if you are running the project as dynamic web project on a server within eclipse, then you should open the project properties (right click > properties) and select "Deployment Assembly". There click "add", select "build path entries", and choose "maven dependencies". This will instruct WTP to send the maven dependencies to the server dir.

Comment: I don't have the "Deployment Assembly" in project properties. What do I do now?..

Comment: Ok, I got it Eclipse pre-3.6 (I've used 3.5) had "Java EE Module Dependencies" section in project properties. But setting checkbox near "Maven Dependencies" there was not enough for me. I had to do "Run on Server" to my WTP project to get those JARs copied to WEB-INF/lib.
I think I had m2eclipse plugin installed, but apparently didn't have WTP support installed from m2e-extras. I'll try installing that later.

Comment: @mvmm m2e-wtp, I'll add it to the answer. But it's optional. You can get it working without it

Comment: I agree with everyone else's sentiment on this one. The third option is exactly what worked for me and hadn't seen that suggested anywhere else but this post. This works in both Indigo and the recently released Juno versions of Eclipse.

Comment: This solution ignores 'provided' scope from pom.xml, so in my case I can't add whole Maven Dependencies to Deployment Assembly. Do you have any workaround for disabling some jars from Maven Dependencies Library?

Comment: yes, the m2e-wtp plugin handles the provided scope jars when it comes to WTP deployment

Comment: After using the 3rd option it works, but if I use the Maven->Update Project, it reverts back and removes the entry from Deployment Assemblies. Any way to work around this?

Comment: Install m2e-wtp, then check project out in workspace, then run mvn clean package, then Run As -> Run on Server. Make sure you delete any previous .\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0) temporary servers that you tried with previously

Comment: The third option should not be needed, as m2e-wtp should do this automatically. I noticed that whenever the libraries are missing from WEB-INF/lib, manually building (Maven build... goal package) would generate a jar with the libs, but the war that's deployed to the AS via m2e-wtp would NOT contain them. Cleaning, closing/opening projects would sometimes bring the libs back.

Comment: Eventually I noticed that when the libs *are* being correctly deployed .classpath contains `<attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>` for the `org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER` entry. As soon as the libs are gone again, this specific attribute is gone too. It's even visible in the local file history that this attribute comes and goes.

Comment: Also ... to add "Dynamic Web Module" (i.e. "Deployment Assembly") - project properties (Right click on project) select "Project Facets", select "Dynamic Web Module", Ok and then do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042475/validating-jdoconfig-with-incorrect-url (Works on Eclipse Juno, Google appengine + GWT + Maven)

Comment: In case yours is a maven dependency of another of your own MySubProject, 
you will not see it under properties>deployment Assembly>Maven Dependencies,   but under   properties>deployment Assembly> MySubProject, 
Closing and opening the projects again did the trick for me, nothing else worked, I am using Neon

Comment: lol, of course I don't want my maven libs deployed, why should I want that?

Answer (score 14):

First install **Maven Integration For Eclipse WTP** (Help->Eclipse Marketplace)

Then in your web project's pom.xml just add:

```
    <packaging>war</packaging>
```

After that just right click the project, Maven -> Update Project, which should automagically add Maven Dependencies for you in the Deployment Assembly.

Comment: +1 That worked for me as well. Without it Maven will package the dependency as a jar and you don't want that, you want that all your dependencies to be packed in a war type file. This has many other effects, read more https://maven.apache.org/pom.html

Comment: maven -> update project worked for me as well. seems necessary in Eclipse Luna version

Answer (score 5):

Right-click project > Maven > Update Maven Project > OK fixed it for me

Answer (score 4):

Check the *Deployment Assembly* property of the project. I have seen some `mvn eclipse:eclipse` generated Eclipse projects sometimes have the assets being deployed to the wrong location. From what I can remember the new *Deployment Assembly* had some issues with earlier versions of Eclipse 3.6 (Helios).

Answer (score 3):

I just did maven -> update project worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

On Eclipse, select your Web Project -> right click -> Properties -> Deployment Assembly -> Add -> Java Build Path Entries -> Maven Dependencies

With this steps, maven libraries will be included on WEB-INF/lib when full publish.

Answer (score 0):

you want to use the copy-dependencies plugin

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97640/force-maven2-to-copy-dependencies-into-target-lib) post and the [docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you look into your deployment and see that WEB-Inf/lib is empty of your Maven dependencies, then ensuring those Maven dependencies are in your deployment assembly is crucial as mention in the chosen answer.

However be wary of Eclipse then not refreshing everything even with a Maven update. If you clean, rebuild and redeploy and still do not see the lib folder being populated try removing and re-adding the application to the server deployments via Servers>Add and Remove.

This unclogged the system for me.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click project -> Deployment Assembly:
See if you have the Maven Dependencies and all others in there.
If not,
Right-Click project -> Maven -> Enable Workspace Resolution

(maybe then Maven -> Update Project, but then look again into "Deployment Assembly" and see what You've got.)
this solved it (finally!) for me.

Comment: If there's no corresponding project configuration in pom.xml and you check the "Update project configuration from pom.xml" when updating project, the Deployment Assembly setting changes will be flushed and set default.