# The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, jstl, tomcat7

I am using JDK 1.7, Apache Tomcat 7.0.23 and I have placed JSTL core library(1.2) and STANDARD jar in WEB_INF lib folder it is not giving me any warning but when I will try to run the code

```html
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<!-- Create Bean Instance-->
<jsp:useBean id="listdomain" class="bean.PopulateMultiDomain" scope="session"></jsp:useBean>

<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="listdomain"/>

<c:forEach var="item" items="${listdomain.status}">
    <option>
        <c:out value="${item}" />
    </option>
</c:forEach>
```

it gives me the following error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:56)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:410)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:117)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTLDLocation(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:311)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:152)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:410)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:475)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1425)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Can anyone suggest me what mistake I am making?

Comment: This is not a duplicate question - in the question linked as a duplicate, the URI is incorrect.  In this one the URI is correct, but the poster gets a similar error.

Comment: for me even though I have devtools set up to reload everything, I had to shut down the server and restart, that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Remove the `standard.jar`. It's apparently of old JSTL 1.0 version when the TLD URIs were without the `/jsp` path. With JSTL 1.2 as available [here](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar) you don't need a `standard.jar` at all. Just the `jstl-1.2.jar` in `/WEB-INF/lib` is sufficient.

#### See also:

- [How to install JSTL? The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/how-to-install-jstl-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-r/)
- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

Comment: @BalusC in `IDEA` the lib folder is not there what is the correct place to add `JSTL` libs in `Intellij IDEA`

Comment: @BalusC In my case i am using jstl 1.1.1 and I am having same issue. After seeing your answer i came to know standard jar is need along with jstl 1.1.1. When i added standard jar to lib, this issue is resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 24):

I solved the same problem. I've just added JSTL-1.2.jar to `/apache-tomcat-x.x.x/lib` and set  scope to provided in maven pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>jstl</groupId>
     <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
     <version>1.2</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: If that was the only thing that worked, then the project/pom in question is apparently not targeted at Tomcat at all, but at a real Java EE server (GlassFish, WildFly, etc). You've then actually other problems.

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you didn't skip **all** jars in

```
tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip
```

in Tomcat catalina.properties.

Answer (score 3):

I have removed the scope and then used a maven update to solve this problem.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    **<!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->**
</dependency>
```

[The jstl lib is not present in the tomcat lib folder.So we have to include it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xws7R.png)
I don't understand why we are told to keep both servlet-api and jstl's scope as provided.

Answer (score 2):

The error in question may also be caused by disabled [JarScanner](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/jar-scanner.html) in `tomcat/conf/context.xml`.

See also [Upgrade from Tomcat 8.0.39 to 8.0.41 results in 'failed to scan' errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42329948/upgrade-from-tomcat-8-0-39-to-8-0-41-results-in-failed-to-scan-errors).

`<JarScanner scanManifest="false"/>` allows to avoid both problems.

Answer (score 2):

if you use spring boot check in `application.propertiese` this property is commented or remove it if exist.

## server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns=*.jar

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse and maven for handling dependencies, you may need to take these extra steps to make sure eclipse copies the dependencies properly [Maven dependencies not visible in WEB-INF/lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083501/maven-dependencies-not-visible-in-web-inf-lib) (namely the Deployment Assembly for Dynamic web application)

Comment: The above link helped me solve my issue on maven dependency and WEB-INF/lib usage in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of the transitive dependencies.

Try to add/ remove the scope from the JSTL library.

This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven project then you just need to add the jstl-1.2 jar in your dependency. If you are simply adding the jar to your project then it's possible that jar file is not added in your project project artifact. You simply need to add the jar file in WEB-INF/lib file.

[image]

This is how your project should look when jstl is not added to the artifact. Just hit the fix button and intellij will add the jar file in the above mentioned path. Run the project and bang.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue, to solve it I have added the below entry in `pom.xml` and performed a `maven update`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```