# Exception got while using JSTL

Tags: java, jstl

I am working in JSTL, while executing Application I got following exception regarding JSTL. Can any one help me out, why I got this exception?

> HTTP Status 500 - The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core
>   cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with
>   this application

Comment: then which URI i have to use?

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701307/the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jsp-jstl-core-cannot-be-resolved-in-either

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701307/the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jsp-jstl-core-cannot-be-resolved-in-either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Exception I got because of jar version problem.
I have downloaded jstl-1.2.jar. Added jar in the class path and rebuilt the jars and executed the application, then the application started working fine.