# Error with my Login Authentication Servlet

Tags: java, mysql, session, servlets, authentication

Please i have some doubt about my ConnectLogin and my ServletValidLogin:
My ConnectLogin

```
    package br.com.cad.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import br.com.cad.basica.Contato;
import br.com.cad.dao.ConnectDb;

public class ConnectLogin extends ConnectDb {

    public Contato getContato( String email, String senha ){

        Connection c = this.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try{


            ps = c.prepareStatement("select pf_email, pf_senha from dados_cadastro where pf_email = ? and pf_senha = ?");
            ps.setString(1, email);
            ps.setString(2, senha);

            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if ( rs.next() ){
                Contato user = new Contato();
                user.setEmail(email);
                user.setSenha(senha);
                user.setNome( rs.getString("pf_nome") );

                return user;
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            if (rs != null ) {
                try { rs.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { ; }
                rs = null;
            }
            if (ps != null ) {
                try { ps.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { ; }
                ps = null;
            }
            if (c != null ) {
                try { c.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { ; }
                c = null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

My Servlet:

```
package br.com.cad.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import br.com.cad.dao.ConnectLogin;
import br.com.cad.basica.Contato;

public class ServletValidaLogin extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                         throws ServletException, IOException{

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(); 
        Contato user = null;
        String email = request.getParameter("email"); 
        String senha = request.getParameter("password"); 

        try {
            ConnectLogin dao = new ConnectLogin(); 
            user = dao.getContato(email, senha);
        }
        catch ( Exception e ){

        }


        if ( user == null ) {
            session.invalidate();
            request.setAttribute("msg", "Usuário ou senha inválidos");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp" ).forward(request, response);
        }
        else{

            session.setAttribute("user", user);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp" ).forward(request, response);
        }

    }

}
```

And my ConnectDb:

```
    package br.com.cad.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class ConnectDb {  

    public Connection getConnection() {  
        try {  
            System.out.println("Connect to database...");  
            return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/soa", "root", "wey123");  
        } catch(SQLException sqlException) {  
            throw new RuntimeException(sqlException);  
        }  
    }
```

I don't know what is wrong and why is returned in my console: Connect to database...
in my webpage is returned user and password invalids! I think the problem is with my ConnectLogin but what?

Comment: You don't include `pf_nome` in the field list of your `SELECT` prepared statement, but you try to query it in the result set.

Comment: OK i fixed but continue error user and password invalids!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "bug" could be one of two things. It could be that you are not even connecting to the database. In `ConnectDb.java` you are throwing a `RunTimeException` but in `ServletValidaLogin.java` you are swallowing that exception. Add a `System.out.println(e.getMessage())` in the `catch` block to make sure that you are indeed able to connect.

```
try {
    ConnectLogin dao = new ConnectLogin(); 
    user = dao.getContato(email, senha);
}
catch ( Exception e ){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
}
```

What will happen in this case is that since you are not connected, you will go to the `catch` block, then your `if` statement in `ServletValidaLogin`

```
if ( user == null )
```

will evaluate to `true` and you will see your error message. Side note:  You are catching **a lot** of exceptions without outputting/logging any of them. You should consider adding `println` statements in all of them. It will make it easier for you to debug.

If you are able to connect, then it could be that your `ResultSet` is not pointing to anything after you execute the query. If that's the case `if ( rs.next() )` will evaluate to `false`in `ConnectLogin.java` and your method will return `null` instead of a user. It could be that you have a bad query (not sure if you should be getting an error message though, I haven't use plain JDBC in a long time). In any case, access mysql directly and add a fake user and try your query on that dummy user. If you can find him than maybe your issue might be in your insertion (ok, so 3 possible causes).

**UPDATE**

It seems like your actual problem was that you were referencing the wrong name in your `getRequest` method for password. We determined that the `name` for attribute `<input>`was actually `senha` and made the necessary changes.

**Note:**
Instead of

```
user.setEmail(email);
user.setSenha(senha);
```

It should be

```
user.setEmail(rs.getString("pf_email"));
user.setSenha(rs.getString("pf_senha"));
```

(although not completely necessary because of your `if`condition but it makes more sense to set them to what the query returns...at least for me).

Also,

```
user.setNome( rs.getString("pf_nome") );
```

should not even be here since it's not in your select statement.

Lastly (unrelated to your main problem), you should seriously consider **synchronizing** `HttpSession`. It is not thread safe. You can read the answer below to get started if you want to know why. There are many more articles on the web that talk about this.

[Is HttpSession thread safe, are set/get Attribute thread safe operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616601/is-httpsession-thread-safe-are-set-get-attribute-thread-safe-operations)

Comment: I fixed it but dont works continues printed in eclipse console: Connect to database... and in form user and password invalid!

Comment: @Wesley Can you tell me what is it that you fixed exactly ? Are you sure you can connect to the db ?

Comment: @Wesley Try to insert a few users through your program and then bring up mysql console directly (NOT through Java). Access the db and run this query `SELECT * FROM dados_cadastro`. Are you seeing the users you inserted in the db ?

Comment: Yeah, in my aplication i have a webform to add user in my DB and they are there stored i saw it through Select * from dados_cadastro and in my login form i insert the email stored in db and your pass but i get a user and password invalid and the consolo Connect to database... as in System.out.Println in my Class ConnectDB

Comment: Now my Class ConnectLogin is: <code>if ( rs.next() ){
                Contato user = new Contato();
                user.setEmail(rs.getString("pf_email"));
                user.setSenha(rs.getString("pf_senha"));
                user.setNome( rs.getString("pf_nome") );
 
                return user;
            }</code>

Comment: I think that i have a problem when i insert my email and passwaord and press submit button in this time my DB dont get a connection but what i dont understand?

Comment: @Wesley What Java version are you using ? Are you also using an IDE ?

Comment: @Wesley. Just to be sure. You are able to confirm that you are not able to connect to the db when you try to insert correct ? Are you also able to connect when you try to retrieve anything from the db also ? Did you add the `println` statement like I told you in the catch block ? Are you seeing an output ? I just want to make sure.

Comment: My IDE is eclipse, I am not able to connect to db when i trying to retrieve data from db...I added the println in catch block but nothing is printed just a message Connect to database... in my console

Comment: @Wesley That does not sound right. Are you sure you're not able to connect ? You should get a `NullPointerException` at some point no or an Exception at least. Let's assume you didn't get an exception and you didn't connect `connection` should be `null` and when you do `c.prepareStatement` you will get a `NullPointerException` thrown at you. The only way to be 100% sure if to open the mysql terminal directly after inserting some values.

Comment: @Wesley When you open the terminal make sure also that your query is correct `select pf_email, pf_senha from dados_cadastro where pf_email = 'something' and pf_senha = 'something'`

Comment: But i insert some values in my mysql throught my Other class that also uses my ConnectDb and i dont get any Exeption or any error. I can not understand where is the error is correct it: public class ConnectLogin extends ConnectDb {... extends is correct?

Comment: @Wesley Let's eliminate some possibilities. Please do the following: Insert some values in the database through your webapp. Then, open the mysql terminal and do `SELECT *` and let me know if it's returning anything ? Do you know how to access the terminal ?

Comment: I know that we can fix it lol... i executed the query in my db and is correct select pf_email, pf_senha from dados_cadastro where pf_email = 'something' and pf_senha = 'something' the data is stored is retrieved.

Comment: @Wesley Ok, and this data that you retireved. It was stored through your webapp ? I'm trying to make sure it's not a connection issue.

Comment: Yeah, i know how to acess the terminal and i just insert some values via terminal and via webform made to create a account. And my data is in my mysql db. I retrieve some values by select * from or select pf_email ...

Comment: @Wesley Ok good lol. Should have said that sooner sheesh. Let me think one moment.

Comment: @Wesley Do me a favor and add a `println` under `String email = request.getParameter("email")` and  `String senha = request.getParameter("password");` Are you getting the same values you entered via the form

Comment: Just println? as 'code'String email = request.getParameter("email");println'code' i dont understand it

Comment: @Wesley Yep, add `System.out.println(email)` and `System.out.println(senha)` under those lines. Then try to log in via webapp and let me know if you are seeing the same values you put in.

Comment: i add so:String email = request.getParameter("email"); 
        System.out.println(email);
        String senha = request.getParameter("password"); 
        System.out.println(senha);

Comment: @Wesley Ok, run your program and let me know what you're seeing ? If you did not see anything you either have the wrong value for `name` attribute of `input` in `getParameter` or you didn't include one at all.

Comment: hum, i got Connect to database...
                wesleyfarias@fiema.org.br
                 null (here should be 123)

Comment: My password(Senha) is got null

Comment: @Wesley Here you go ! I'm betting the name of your `input` was `senha` and not `password` right ?

Comment: @Wesley In other words your input in the HTML for password should be defined as below `<input type="text" name="password">`. You either forgot to add the `name` attribute or the `name` has a different value right ?

Comment: i think that works but i received this error: HTTP Status 500 - The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Comment: @Wesley If the input name is senha then change this `request.getParameter("password");` to `request.getParameter("senha");`

Comment: @Wesley Are you using Maven ? Try to do a clean and build

Comment: whats mean it?org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:56)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:445)
 ...

Comment: Are you using Maven ? Try to do a clean and build  - i dont use MAVEN

Comment: @Wesley Try to relaunch the application.

Comment: @Wesley http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701307/the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jsp-jstl-core-cannot-be-resolved-in-either

Comment: @Wesley It only took us 31 comments lol but we were able to solve it. Good luck with everything.

Comment: Thanks for help me you are great programmer now i have a other problem HTTP Status 500 - The absolute uri: java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.jav‌​a:56) org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:445) that i look a solution...Thanks!!

Comment: @Wesley Lol, I'm not. I ran into your problem a lot. Can you post a new discussion thread ? We're not really suppose to put so many comments and I don't want to get in trouble. Once you ask the question, leave me a comment with the link and I'll look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into Spring, and [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/), Spring offers good tested system to secure website and manage db connections.

Currently it supports DB-backed, JNDI-backed security or you can just hardcode users and roles. With spring you can secure just sections of the site or methods

Here is more info about security itself http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html

Comment: I highly doubt OP will look into that since he is having trouble with plain JDBC. Then again, you never know.