# Tomcat7 WEB-INF/lib directory doesen't work

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jstl, jsp-tags

I'm new with jsp pages and just yesterday I opened a similar discussion.
This could be a repeat or a very similar one and I'm so sorry whether this is the case, but are just few days that I'm developing jsp pages and I haven't understood how the enviroment, the folders, etc are "linked" together.

I got the following error on *Apache Tomcat 7*

```
HTTP Status 500 - The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

because I included this *taglib*

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Then, I created a folder "lib" into the "WEB-INF" one and I put there the file *jstl-1-2.jar*.
A user suggested into another discussion reachable from here
[The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701307/the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jsp-jstl-core-cannot-be-resolved-in-either/8701326#8701326)
to remove the *standard.jar* but I have never had a similar file.

Reading and surfing on the web, I read that in *Tomcat 7* should be sufficient to put *jstl-1-2.jar* into the WEB-INF/lib folder like below but both with and without that file, nothing happen. The error doesen't change.

```
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/jsp_test/web/WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1-2.jar
```

This is the folders three:

```
- webapps - ROOT - index.html
                 - META-INF - context.xml

          - jsp_test - nbproject
                     - src - conf - MANIFEST.MF
                           - java - mypack - Display.java

                     - web - ROOT    - index.jsp
                           - WEB-INF - lib       -jstl-1.2.jar
                                     - web.xml
                                     - beans.xml
```

I noticed also that there's another *web.xml* file also into the tomcat 7 folder:

```
/etc/tomcat7/web.xml
```

Do I have to change something in both the *web.xml* files?

Moreover, looking in the tomcat7-example folder there is a *web.xml* file where many libraries are written with a .tld extention:

```
/usr/share/tomcat7-examples/examples/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

I lost my way for this stupid thing, help me please! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn how to properly create and deploy a web app on Tomcat.

Get rid of that `/web` folder under your `/jsp_test` root.  You should just have `/WEB-INF` and its children under the root.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the content of the url : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info. It might help you in resolving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Like duffymo said je webapp structure should probably look like this:
Notice that I also removed the 'ROOT' dir under 'jsp_test' not sure why you added this dir. You can now access your index.jsp directly from the root of your domain.

```
- webapps - ROOT - index.html
                 - META-INF - context.xml

          - jsp_test - index.jsp
                     - WEB-INF - lib       -jstl-1.2.jar
                               - web.xml
                               - beans.xml
```

Well i'm curious what url you used to access the index.jsp to get the 500-error?

something like 'http://yourdomain.net/jsp_test/web/ROOT/index.jsp'?

Now the url to acces index.jsp should look like: 'http://yourdomain.net/jsp_test/index.jsp'

I don't know if you configured a context root for you application in tomcat, but if you did and mapped it on 'jsp_test' the url becomes: 'http://yourdomain.net/index.jsp'

If you are just working on a development environment with your tomcat webserver it is also very convenient to place your application in the ROOT webapp of tomcat. Just get rid of the current ROOT webapp and replace it with yours, so your structure will look like:

```
- webapps - ROOT - index.jsp
                 - WEB-INF - lib       -jstl-1.2.jar
                           - web.xml
                           - beans.xml
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response.
I'll try your solution and let you updade about it.

About the url, I configured a new host in _server.xml_ file, then i go to the _http://jsp.test:8080/_

Obviously i'm in local enviroment :)

Comment: If you use the ROOT webapp there no need to configure the server.xml you can just access your application at http://127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: Yes i know it but i had no problems about the _server.xml_ configuration, in fact it works good on the local domain which i've set up

Comment: You should not have to touch webapps/ROOT or modify server.xml at all.  All you need to do is create a proper WAR file and put that under /webapps.  Anything else is the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that i've just resolved the issue.

Hoping that the it will be useful for someone, below thers's my solution.

I deleted the old project and i put up a new one in a new directory named "tsp_test" at the same level of the *webapps* one.

After the set up of a new host into the *server.xml*, i built a new folder structure for the project:

```
- tomcat7 - jsp_test - conf
                     - java - mypack - Display.java
                     - test
                     - ROOT - META-INF - context.xml
                            - WEB-INF  - web.xml
                                       - lib         - jstl-1.2.jar
                            - index.jsp
```

Now i got another error which not concern with the *taglib* issue:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP
```

I think that it could be because of some class error.

Thank you for the help!