# How to use JSP on Servlet doPOst?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I just started to use JSP and Servlet and i am trying to make a controller for a device. A simple page with 4 buttons. Each time when one of the buttons is clicked, the user should see  something displayed(according with the pressed button). I am trying to do that by using a  Servlet and JSP. I am not sure if this is a good approach, but the problem is that i am not doing this well, because when i run my application, i can see the 4 buttons, but on click them nothing happens. What i am doing wrong? I would appreciate some suggestions for another approach.

MainServlet

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class CheckTemperature
 */
@WebServlet("/CheckTemperature")
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public MainServlet() {
        super();      
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head><title>Check tempetaure</title></head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Check temperature\" name=\"button\"/>");
        out.println("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Get AC state\" name=\"button\"/>");
        out.println("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Turn ON AC\" name=\"button\"/>");
        out.println("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Turn OFF AC\" name=\"button\"/>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");     
    }
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String button = request.getParameter("button");
        if(button.equalsIgnoreCase("Check temperature")){
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsps/checkTemperature.jsp").include(request, response);
        } else if(button.equalsIgnoreCase("Get AC state")){
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsps/acState.jsp").include(request, response);
        } else if(button.equalsIgnoreCase("Turn ON AC")){
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsps/turnOn.jsp").include(request, response);
        } else if(button.equalsIgnoreCase("Turn OFF AC")){
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsps/turnOff.jsp").include(request, response);
        }           
    }    
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>ArduinoController</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>ACController</display-name>
    <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ro.dnad.controller.MainServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/main</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

checkTemperature.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="ro.dnad.controller.EthernetACDriver" %>

<%EthernetACDriver driver = new EthernetACDriver("localhost",8080); %>
<%double temp = driver.getTemperature() * 5; %>
<%=temp%>
```

acState.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="ro.dnad.controller.EthernetACDriver" %>

<%EthernetACDriver driver = new EthernetACDriver("localhost",8080); %>
<%=driver.ACStatus()%>
```

turnOff.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="ro.dnad.controller.EthernetACDriver" %>

<%EthernetACDriver driver = new EthernetACDriver("localhost",8080); %>
<%driver.sendMessage(3); %>
<%=driver.ACStatus()%>
```

turnOfn.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="ro.dnad.controller.EthernetACDriver" %>

<%EthernetACDriver driver = new EthernetACDriver("localhost",8080); %>
<%driver.sendMessage(2); %>
<%=driver.ACStatus()%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all rather than using servlet for creating dynamic content, you should use JSP
- For working your code you need to add each submit but inside the form. Then only submit button will work.

Code sample:

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head><title>Check tempetaure</title></head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<form action='CheckTemperature' method='post'>");

        out.println("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Check temperature\" name=\"button\"/>");
        out.println("<form />");
        out.println("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Get AC state\" name=\"button\"/>");
        out.println("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Turn ON AC\" name=\"button\"/>");
        out.println("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Turn OFF AC\" name=\"button\"/>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");     
    }
```

Comment: One more thing: do not generate the whole HTML source directly in servlet, instead forward to another page.

Comment: Also, OP's asking about a POST request, not a GET

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thank you for your answer. I will try to create a JSP instead of generating the html source from servlet.

Answer (score 0):

> when i run my application, i can see the 4 buttons, but on click them
>   nothing happens

because you have not provided any action to perform nor the buttons are inside form.

Also you have mapped your `Servlet` two times :

1. using `@WebServlet("/CheckTemperature")`
2. and using `url-pattern` in web.xml, choose one.

you learning in old way, i.e.

- Avoid `scriptlets(<% %>, <%= %>)` instead use [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL3.html) or other tag library's.
- Instead of writing Java codes in jsp, use `Model/Service` class for keeping bussiness logic's separate from view. then you can easily DEBUG your code, while not in jsp.
- don't hard code to generate html codes in servlets. instead create static `HTML/jsp` page .with a `form` by giving `action` value as `Servlet` url-pattern and method type as `GET/POST`, then after filling details submit the from, handle the form in servlet then, finally forward response to `jsp/html` page.

---

Solution:

Servlet:

```
/**
* Servlet implementation class CheckTemperature
*/
@WebServlet("/CheckTemperature")
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  /**
   * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   */
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      String button = request.getParameter("button");

      EthernetACDriver driver = new EthernetACDriver("localhost",8080);

      if(button.equalsIgnoreCase("Check temperature")){
         double temp = driver.getTemperature() * 5;
         request.setAttribute("temp", temp);// add temperature value to request
         RequestDispatcher dispatcher =
                 request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsps/checkTemperature.jsp");
         dispatcher.forward(request,response);
      } else if(button.equalsIgnoreCase("Get AC state")){
         request.setAttribute("acStatus", driver.ACStatus()); // add AC status value to request
         RequestDispatcher dispatcher =
                 request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsps/acState.jsp");          
         dispatcher.forward(request,response);
      } else if(button.equalsIgnoreCase("Turn ON AC")){
         driver.sendMessage(3);
         request.setAttribute("acTurnOnMsg", driver.ACStatus());// add AC turn on status value to request        
         RequestDispatcher dispatcher =
                 request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsps/turnOn.jsp");                
         dispatcher.forward(request,response);
      } else if(button.equalsIgnoreCase("Turn OFF AC")){
         driver.sendMessage(3);
         request.setAttribute("acTurnOffMsg", driver.ACStatus()); //AC turn off status value to request
         RequestDispatcher dispatcher =
                 request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsps/turnOff.jsp");      
         dispatcher.forward(request,response);
      }           
  }    
}
```

and in JSP use expression like:
add

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

in top of jsp.

then

checkTemperature.jsp:

`${temp}` // get temperature value from request.

acState.jsp:

`${acStatus}` //get AC status value from request

turnOff.jsp:

`${acTurnOnMsg}` //get AC turn on status value from request

turnOfn.jsp:

`${acTurnOffMsg}` //get AC turn on status value from request

**EDIT:**
JSP:

```
<c:url value="/CheckTemperature" var="postUrl"/>
<form action="${postUrl}" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Check temperature" name="button"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Get AC state" name="button"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Turn ON AC" name="button"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Turn OFF AC" name="button"/>
</form>
```

[get JSTL here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.2)

Comment: Rembo, i created a jsp file for the doGet method and update the doPost and the others jsp files as you suggested, the main page gets to be displayed, but when i click a button i get HTTP 404 error.

Comment: what action you have in form tag?

Comment: <url-pattern>/main</url-pattern> and <form action="main" method="post">

Comment: @laura no need of `url-pattern` and servlet registration in web.xml, if you have annotated with `@WebServlet`, just specify the jsp you have form element as welcome-file in web.xml. will work fine.

Comment: I get this error now: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Comment: you have forgot to add JSTL jar in CLASSPATH, add it. have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701307/the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jsp-jstl-core-cannot-be-resolved-in-either)

Comment: i have JSTL jar in the BUILDPATH and this is bad..is not in the classpath