# Upgrade from Tomcat 8.0.39 to 8.0.41 results in 'failed to scan' errors

Tags: java, file, tomcat, jar, upgrade

I have a Spring Boot WAR application perfectly working under Tomcat 8.0.39 on AWS. After issuing `sudo service tomcat8 stop`, upgrading to Tomcat 8.0.41 through `sudo yum update`, and rebooting the instance, the application does not start. In the catalina log file, I see a ton of exceptions of the type:

```
19-Feb-2017 10:27:15.326 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.
scan.StandardJarScanner.scan Failed to scan [file:/usr/share/java/tomcat8/javax.
annotation-api.jar] from classloader hierarchy
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/java/tomcat8/javax.annotation-api.jar
 (No such file or directory)
```

Here are the files Tomcat complains about:

```
javax.annotation-api.jar
jsr181-api.jar
jaxb-api.jar
javax.xml.soap-api.jar
FastInfoset.jar
mimepull.jar
saaj-impl.jar
stax2-api.jar
woodstox-core-asl.jar
jaxb-core-2.2.10-b140802.1033.jar
jaxb-api-2.2.12-b140109.1041.jar
istack-commons-runtime-2.19.jar
txw2-2.2.10-b140802.1033.jar
hk2-core.jar
class-model.jar
config.jar
auto-depends.jar
javax.inject.jar
hk2-api.jar
osgi-resource-locator.jar
tiger-types.jar
bean-validator.jar
jtype.jar
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

---

**Update #1:**

Some of the above files belong to `jaxws-ri`. It turned out that I had some (10), but not all (23), of the jars from JAX-WS RI 2.2.10 `lib` directory copied into Tomcat's `lib` directory. After copying the missing 13 jars, the list of files Tomcat complains about in the catalina log file has shrunk to:

```
jaxb-core-2.2.10-b140802.1033.jar
jaxb-api-2.2.12-b140109.1041.jar
istack-commons-runtime-2.19.jar
txw2-2.2.10-b140802.1033.jar
hk2-core.jar
class-model.jar
config.jar
auto-depends.jar
javax.inject.jar
hk2-api.jar
osgi-resource-locator.jar
tiger-types.jar
bean-validator.jar
jtype.jar
```

(Exceptions for the above files are repeated several times in the log file. Looks like the scanner is invoked repeatedly at startup, perhaps scanning different class paths.)

This tells me that with the transition from 8.0.39 to 8.0.41, Tomcat suddenly became very picky about the presence of all referenced jars, even though the application works perfectly fine without many of them. In addition, Tomcat appears to be very particular about specific builds of some jars (e.g. see the `jaxb-core...` and `jaxb-api...` jars above).

Now, to fix this I could try to find all these missing jars and copy them to Tomcat's `lib` directory. However, I see no way of assuring the proper source for some of them due to generic names, such as `config.jar`, or missing version numbers.

So, is there a way to prevent Tomcat's `scan.StandardJarScanner.scan` from being so picky about all these jars?

---

**Update #2:**

It turns out that in Tomcat 8.0.38, a setting was added to control jar scanning, the value of which defaults to `true`. To turn scanning off, add the following line in `context.xml`:

```
<Context>
  ...
  <JarScanner scanManifest="false"/>
</Context>
```

For details, see
[Provide an option to disable processing of Class-Path entry in a jar's manifest file](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59961).

Comment: The files do not exist. If Tomcat 8.0.41 requires them (and 8.0.39 obviously did not), then they should come with the `yum update` but apparently they did not.

Comment: So start with `rpm -ql tomcat|more` to see what was installed and make sure the files are actually missing and not somewhere unexpected.

Answer (score 20):

There was a bug, that Tomcat 8 ignores the [`Class-Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) header in the [`MANIFEST.MF`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) file of a JAR, see [Bug 59226](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59226):

> Bug 59226  - StandardJarScanner ignores jars in manifest Class-path header

This bug was fixed with Tomcat 8.0.34, but it produced a lot of warnings for not required JARs, see [Bug 59961](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59961):

> Bug 59961  - Provide an option to disable processing of Class-Path entry in a jar's manifest file

Since Tomcat 8.0.38 you can disable the scan of the `MANIFEST.MF` file, see [The Jar Scanner Component](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/jar-scanner.html):

> scanManifest
>
> If true, the Manifest files of any JARs found will be scanned for additional class path entires and those entries will be added to the URLs to scan. The default is true.

Answer (score 1):

you can add the below line

I had the same issue

###### server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns=*.jar

In application.properties file