# Static attribute must be a String literal, when using <%@ page isELIgnored ="false" %>

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

im using the jsp page and jstl following tag.

```
 <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
 <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
 <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic" %>
 <%@ taglib prefix="vlh" uri="/WEB-INF/tld/valuelist.tld" %>
 <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
 <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
 <%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
 <%@ page import="java.util.Locale" %>
  <%@ page isELIgnored ="false" %>

 ...... <c:forEach items="${list}" var="productInfo">
```

when i run this it was shows following error...

```
  selectLoginProfile.jsp:144:17: Static attribute must be a String literal, its illegal to specify an expression.
          <c:forEach items="${list}" var="productInfo">
                                 ^---^
 selectLoginProfile.jsp:148:70: Static attribute must be a String literal, its illegal to specify an expression.
                document.ProfileLoginForm.userName.value='<c:out value="${userInfo.userName}"/>';
                                                                 ^---^
```

Comment: What is ur jstl version?

Comment: using jstl 1.2 @NehaShettar

Comment: when i was remove this line
     <%@ page isELIgnored ="false" %>
that time work in good in eclipse and not work in .ear file deployment but if add that line means .ear file working but eclipse not work.

Comment: Hey Refer this answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8701326/4792039

Comment: I'm not  using standard.jar but the error is comming @NehaShettar

Comment: Tried with core_rt?

Comment: no use that time also error  is show.

Answer (score 2):

Replace you core taglib

`<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`

with

`<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`

Comment: Also try once using core_rt and fmt_rt i.e  <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c" %>    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt" prefix="fmt" %>

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I had to do the opposite. I was using http://java.sun.com/jstl/core and changed to http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core and that fixed the problem.