# JasperException using www.springframework.org/tags/form

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I decided to ask this question because none of answers found helped me to figure this out. I try running my app (tomcat with add.jsp file) and I'm getting

`JasperException: The absolute uri: [http://www.springframework.org/tags/form] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application.`

I've been trying to resolve this issue for about week and I ran out of ideas, so I'll be greatful for any clues.

I work with:
 
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.3 (Ultimate Edition)
 
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b38 amd64
 
apache-tomcat-9.0.8

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>movie</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.moviedatabase</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>movie-webapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.moviedatabase</groupId>
            <artifactId>movie-application</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Baza filmów</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

add.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Dodaj film</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="list.jsp">Powrót do listy filmów</a><br />
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="movieDto">
    <table border="1">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Tytuł</th>
            <td><form:input type="text" path="title"/><c:if test="${pageContext.request.method=='POST'}"><form:errors
                    path="title"/></c:if></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Autor</th>
            <td><form:input type="text" path="author"/><c:if test="${pageContext.request.method=='POST'}"><form:errors
                    path="author"/></c:if></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Rok wydania</th>
            <td><form:input type="text" path="year"/><c:if test="${pageContext.request.method=='POST'}"><form:errors
                    path="year"/></c:if></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Dodaj!" /></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form:form>
<br />
<hr />
</body>
</html>
```

HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message The absolute uri: [http://www.springframework.org/tags/form] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: [http://www.springframework.org/tags/form] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:55)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:294)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:81)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTldResourcePath(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:251)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:122)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:431)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:489)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1445)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:144)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:105)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:206)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:346)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
Apache Tomcat/9.0.8

Comment: related to this i wonder?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701307/the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jsp-jstl-core-cannot-be-resolved-in-either/8701326?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I had this issue too, but I found solution here. Anyway I tried change jars to skip in catalina.properties, but it didn't work. Thank you anyway!