# Eclipse -The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I read all the posts regarding this error but for some reason it does not work for me...

Here is my folder structure,

[image]

I get the error as mentioned in my title,

The code of the if_tag.jsp,

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<title><c:if> Tag Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:set var="salary" scope="session" value="${2000*2}"/>
<c:if test="${salary > 2000}">
   <p>My salary is: <c:out value="${salary}"/><p>
</c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

The jstl libraries are located in -

```
C:\tomcat\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the maven project as dynamic web project on a server within eclipse, then you should follow the following steps!

open the project properties by right click on the **project > properties** and select **Deployment Assembly**.

Click **add**, select **Java build path entries**, and choose **maven dependencies** and then click Finish and Apply.

hope, it may work. it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

JSTL uses different URIs. You just need to get the right version of it.
You could download using [JSTL 1.2](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) or download the JSTL 1.1 jars.

[Javaranch](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/JstlTagLibDefinitions) has more detailed list of version/URIs.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to note that if you have a project that is Maven based, and you import it into eclipse but receive this error absolute URI, then you might need to follow these directions [Maven dependencies not visible in WEB-INF/lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083501/maven-dependencies-not-visible-in-web-inf-lib) (namely the Deployment assembly step)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue copy and paste the jstl-1.2.jar file into your WEB-INF/lib folder directory. This will fix your issue.