# Docusign java integration having error " http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, docusignapi

I'm integrating docuSign with java using the url https://github.com/docusign/qs-java. And I'm using java 1.8. I have got the error as follows.

```
Tests run: 2, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.387 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.docusign.HelloControllerTest
testHello(com.docusign.HelloControllerTest)  Time elapsed: 1.855 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Response body doesn't match expectation.
Expected: is "Hello World!"
  Actual: {"timestamp":1556517506260,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.apache.jasper.JasperException","message":"The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application","path":"/"}
```

### pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- To compile JSP files -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

### index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<jsp:include page="../partials/head.jsp"/>
```

I have tried with the dependency as follows. But don't solve the problem.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Anyone please help me with this to sort out. Any help would be appreciable

Answer (score 0):

the java code has the tags coming from that url as you can see in something like

```
%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

You can remove these, but they should work. Not sure what Java environment you are using.

Seems like you can get your answer here - [Eclipse -The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347458/eclipse-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jsp-jstl-core-cannot-be-resolved)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. 
Change `<jsp:include page="../partials/head.jsp"/>` 
to `<%@ include file ="../partials/head.jsp" %>`'