# Maven java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/query/Query

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, pom.xml, java-ee-6

I'm working on a project and it kept generating error when runing the project.

I need help to solve this issue please, thank you in advance.

**UPDATE** -------------------------------

I'm still struggling with this issue, in the beginning when i was trying to test the methods everythings works fine, all the insert, update, delete... but when i added Servlet I got these errors.

---

This is my first time using Maven and Hibernate and it's giving tons of errors such as

> `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/query/Query at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1407) at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1215)`

I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083501/maven-dependencies-not-visible-in-web-inf-lib/6083776#6083776) it works (the servlet works too) for a little while then back to the same problem again.

`pom.xml` :

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
          <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        
          <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
          <artifactId>GestionDesAchats1</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
          <packaging>war</packaging>
        
          <name>SchoolProject Maven Webapp</name>
          <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
          <url>http://www.example.com</url>
        
          <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
          </properties>
        
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>junit</groupId>
              <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
              <version>4.11</version>
              <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
              <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
              <version>5.6.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2-b02</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
              <groupId>mysql</groupId>
              <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
              <version>8.0.27</version>
            </dependency>
            
          </dependencies>
        
          <build>
            <finalName>SchoolProject </finalName>
            <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
              <plugins>
                <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>3.2.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
              </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
          </build>
        </project>
```

`jars` :

[image]

`Error`

[image]

---

**update2**
I couldn't fix the problem so I switched to Dynamic web Project, and now everything works fine, i didn't even had to change a piece of code or add other jars.

Comment: Can you share your java code?

Answer (score 1):

Try running an `mvn dependency:tree` to see what your classpath looks like.

There is a **compatibility matrix** between hibernate, REST and other components. That means you have to **use the right versions together**. It's often non-trivial to figure out which ones to combine, but `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` will give you insight where you overwrite versions. These days, most platforms have a website to generate a compatible pom for you ([Quarkus](https://code.quarkus.io/), Spring, etc). But old-school `war` based deployments typically don't have that yet. Non-war based deployments of Hibernate with Rest look differently: [here's an example](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/main/hibernate-orm-quickstart).

A quick search shows that the class `org.hibernate.query.Query` existed in hibernate-core 5.2, but not in 5.6, where it got moved to org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm.

Try adding a dependency on hibernate-search-orm too:

```
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
          <version>5.6.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I added this this dependency and ran `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose ` and got this warning `[WARNING] The artifact xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.0.2 has been relocated to xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2`

Comment: Unrelated to fix your issue, but a good sign of how hard dependency managment and the compatibility matrix is - and how it's easier to let the upstream platform handle that pain for you, by importing a platform bom to handle the versions for you.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this issue, in the beginning when i was trying to test the methods everythings worked fine, all the insert int database, update, delete... but when i added Servlet I got these errors? do you have any idea how to solve it please  ?

Comment: Is there some light for this question? We're with the same problem. Locally WildFly runs normally. Therefore, running inside Jenkins this trouble ocurrs to this class: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Query