# Spring JDO configuration parsing error

Tags: spring, validation, config, jdo

I have a spring test case that annotated as following

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:conf/allocadia-base.xml", "classpath:META-INF/jdoconfig.xml"})
```

my jdoconfig is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig">
```

when I run the test I get

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext 
.  
. 
.  
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 4 in XML document from class path resource [META-INF/jdoconfig.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'jdoconfig'.
```

if I changed jdoconfig to

```
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig_2_3.xsd">
```

the error is

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
>   Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for
>   XML schema namespace [http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig]
>   Offending resource: class path resource [META-INF/jdoconfig.xml]

I use the latest spring 3.2 and JDO 2.3-e

the application works fine when I deploy it to tomcat I'm just getting this error when trying to run the test

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your jdoconfig.xml consist incorrect url. Try this:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig_3_0.xsd"
```

[Validating jdoconfig with incorrect url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042475/validating-jdoconfig-with-incorrect-url)

[How to solve validation error on xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation in jdoconfig.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654503/how-to-solve-validation-error-on-xsinonamespaceschemalocation-in-jdoconfig-xml)